# How to Post Dynamic angular form data to a nested mongoose Schema?

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

I have written a schema @Requirement.

**I have some challenges in creating dynamic Categories, Items, and groups, etc. in the same Menu schema.**

Client-side code for my real schema:

```
    $scope.create = function () {
          var Timings={
            'open': this.open,
            'close': this.close
        };
        var SubitemGroup={
            'name ': this.name,

        };
        var Items= {
            'name': this.item_name,
            'sort': this.item_sort,
            'description': this.item_description,
            'price': this.item_price,
            ' 

             'timings': {
              'mon': [Timings],
                'tue': [Timings],
               'wed': [Timings],
               'thu': [Timings],
               'fri': [Timings],
                'sat': [Timings],
             'sun': [Timings]

            }

        };
        var Category={
            name : this.categoryname,
            description : this.categorydescription,
            items:[Items]
       };

        var menusObj= {
            'menuname' : this.menuName,
            'description' : this.menu_description,
             'address':{
             'city':this.city,
                } ,
         'categories':[Category]
      };
};
```

I used an **Angular Form** to post all the values to the server. This adds all the fields as Mongoose Schema Fields:

```
<form name="menuForm" class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': menuForm.menuName.$dirty && menuForm.title.$invalid }">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="menu_Name">Display Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="menuName" type="text" data-ng-model="menuName" id="menuName" class="form-control" placeholder="Display Name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
// same Code  for all the fields 

{{ menuForm }}

           <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            </div>

        </fieldset></form>
```

How can I create dynamic Categories, Items, SubItems, etc. to the same menu? Is it possible with the existing schema or do I need to split the existing Schema into different schemas where we can connect them with references.

Comment: could you clarify a bit you are are looking for, I have 73% understanding of what you mean, let's rise it to the 100%

Comment: I need to create Number of  Categories, Items ,Sub items etc ... how could we do it By using Dynamic Forms in Angular JS? ... or Splitting Schema in to Multiple Schams Help ???

Comment: Alright you might like this : https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms , generally look for npm / bower packages they have solution for everything.